# How can I set a cookie to specific path in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I m developing angularjs project. in here I create a cookie in https:// localhost:8080/private/ path. But I need to create it in here https:// localhost:8080/ . So how can I do it?

I want to set this cookie Id to specific path like https:// localhost:8080/ in angular js

```
$cookies.contactId = data.id;
```